# Trouble while disabling 7 days before active date

Tags: datepicker

I'm trying to make the datepicker disable 1 week from the current date.
The code is for a datepicker for room reservation using an onRender function.
Please help me :(

```
$(function() {
        var nowTemp = new Date();
        var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

        var checkin = $('#ad').datepicker({
          onRender: function(date) {
            return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
          }
        }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
          if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
            var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
            checkout.setValue(newDate);
          }
          checkin.hide();
          $('#dpd2')[0].focus();
        }).data('datepicker');
        var checkout = $('#dd').datepicker({
          onRender: function(date) {
            return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
          }
        }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
          checkout.hide();
        }).data('datepicker');
            });
```